# Sqlite query on uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, win-universal-app

How to code the UWP for sqlite query below:

```
Select word, translation 
from ind_dict 
where word like '?%'
```

I try to enter the code below, but the error message as shown below:

[image]

Code:

```
using (var statement = _connection.Prepare("SELECT word, translation FROM " + TABLE_NAME_IND + " WHERE word like '?%'"))
{
    //Ind.Word = inputText.Text;
    statement.Bind(1, Ind.Word);
    SQLiteResult result = statement.Step();

    if (SQLiteResult.ROW == result)
    {
        value = statement[Ind.Word] as String;
        value = statement[Ind.Translation] as String;
        indDatasource.Add(Ind);

        if (indDatasource.Count > 0)
        {
            translation.ItemsSource = indDatasource;
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and exception information, I think you are using [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/) in your code.

In Portable Class Library for SQLite, the **`Bind`** method is used to bind parameters in SQL command to their actual values like following:

```
using (var statement = connection.Prepare(@"INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName)
                                            VALUES(@firstName, @lastName);"))
{
    statement.Bind("@firstName", "Donald");
    statement.Bind("@lastName", "Duck");

    // Inserts data.
    statement.Step();
}
```

Since there is no parameter in your query, you needn't and also can't use `Bind` method here.

Then to retrieve the actual values form `statement`, we need to use the indexer or column name on the `statement` object to specify the column that we want to retrieve. Besides, as the query command may return multiple rows, we'd better use a while loop to get all data. And once we finished reading one row, we need to call `statement.Step()` method to go to next row. So the code for executing query command may like following:

```
using (var _connection = new SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection(sqlpath))
{
    using (var statement = _connection.Prepare("SELECT word, translation FROM " + TABLE_NAME_IND + " WHERE word like '?%'"))
    {
        while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
        {
            ind_dict Ind = new ind_dict();
            Ind.Word = statement["word"] as String;
            Ind.Translation = statement["translation"] as String;

            indDatasource.Add(Ind);
        }
    }
}

if (indDatasource.Count > 0)
{
    translation.ItemsSource = indDatasource;
}
```

For more info about how to use this Portable Class Library for SQLite, you can refer to this blog: [The new Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/the-new-portable-class-library-for-sqlite/).